# React Cannot find module - ttf, otf fonts

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, styled-components

I'm trying to load local font like the code below but I keep getting `Cannot find module '@/landing/fonts/Gotham-Bold.ttf'` error and have no idea what is really wrong this path.

my folder structure looks like this, and the code I'm working on is `LandingPage.tsx`

[image]

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import font from './fonts/Gotham-Bold.ttf'

const Gotham = createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src:
      url(${font}) format('truetype'),
  }
`
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: This is what worked for me. Import like this...

   src: url('../assets/fonts/gilroy/gilroy.woff2') format('woff2');

Answer (score 34):

Know this a bit old but it could be a problem with Typescript. When using a font file with Typescript you have to declare the formats as a module.

For that you can create a `fonts.d.ts` file and add the following code inside it:

```
declare module '*.ttf';
```

That way Typescript will know how to handle .ttf files.
You also will need a appropriate [Webpack loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/).

Comment: This throws `Invalid module name in augmentation, module '*.ttf' cannot be found.` for me.

Comment: Just to clarify, cause it took me a while to figure our where to put the file, it should go in the very same `fonts` folder that you create to store the `.ttf` files.

In my case at least, this solved the whole issue, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We need to add a declaration file, and tell Typescript that .ttf files can be imported as modules. I did so as follows:

```js
// file: src/assets/fonts/fonts.d.ts

declare module "*.ttf";
```

#### That file(`fonts.d.ts`) must be near with font file

Answer (score -1):

According to your folder structure LandingPages.tsx is inside pages folder. The pages folder is a sibling of the fonts folder. You need to traverse to fonts folder from inside of pages folder.

The correct path will be `'.././fonts/Gotham-Bold.ttf'`

You need to move one level up (..) and then go to the fonts folder.

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: this doesn't work. and react will display an error 'Cannot find module'

Comment: Could it be that you have the dots in the reverse order? I'm pretty sure it should go like `./../fonts/etc.ttf`